# Convert datetime.time in Python to time class in R

Tags: r, python-3.x, datetime, lubridate, reticulate

I am reading a python dataframe into R and generating some Rmd reports. I use reticulate with condaenv to call py_run_file to run the python script that generates the dataframe. The python script uses pandas datetime objects.
When I read the data into R with the convert flag set to False, **py_run_file**(*filename*, convert=F), I end up with environments for both date and time columns from which I need to extract the actual date and time values.

data$date <- do.call(c, lapply(seq_along(data$date), function(j) py_to_r(date$date[[j]])))

This works well to convert the date column. The same does not work for the time column.

date        time

2023-06-05  08:55:37

2023-06-05  08:56:26

> data$date[[1]]

datetime.date(2023, 6, 13)

For extracting the date component from the environment, I am able to use the **py_to_r **function as below:

data$date <- do.call(c, lapply(seq_along(data$date), function(j) py_to_r(date$date[[j]])))

> data$date[[1]]

[1] "2023-06-05"

However, I am at a loss at converting the time component. The same commands above do not help. Any help will be appreciated.

data$time <- do.call(c, lapply(seq_along(data$time), function(j) py_to_r(date$time[[j]])))

> data$time[[1]]

datetime.time(8, 55, 37)

I checked the datatype after the two commands and I get the following:

> class(data$date)

[1] "Date"

> class(data$time)

[1] "list"

Comment: what is the object you ended up with? try `as.Date()` ? could you provide code sample?

Comment: Base R does not have time object/class. You need to combine tim,e and date to be able to read the time into R.

Comment: I am using lubridate, reticulate and tidyverse.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(hms)
library(reticulate)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

pyFile <- 'filename.py'
py_run_file(pyFile, convert = F)

data <- py$df
```

Convert date and time from python objects into R variables.

To convert to date format.

```
data$date <- do.call(c, lapply(seq_along(data$date), function(j) py_to_r(data$date[[j]])))
```

To convert to time format using the `parse_hms` function from `hms` library.

```
data$time <- do.call(c, lapply(seq_along(data$time), function(j) parse_hms(data$time[[j]])))
```